# Different sorting order in dictionay and list

Tags: python-2.7, oracle11g

I have to fetch all column names and types from an Oracle database, and then depending on a column type do different things.

My code is:

```
for tab in table_list:
    tables = {}#tabel list
    table_types = {} #for each table dictionary column_name: type
    cur.execute("select column_name, data_type from all_tab_cols where owner = 'AAA' and table_name = '"+tab+"' and hidden_column = 'NO' order by column_id asc")
    res = cur.fetchall()
    for type in res:
        table_types[type[0]] = type[1]
    tables[tab]=table_types

    print res
    print table_types
```

For `res` I get:

```
[('COAG_ID', 'NUMBER'), ('COAG_CONT_ID', 'NUMBER'), ('COAG_CONT_OPER_ID', 'NUMBER'), ('COAG_CAGT_ID', 'NUMBER'), etc...
```

And for `table_types` i get:

```
{'COAG_DELIVERY_PAYER': 'VARCHAR2', 'COAG_AGREEMENT_DATE': 'DATE', 'COAG_HANDSET_FULL_PRICE': 'NUMBER', etc...
```

My question is: why aren't the values in the same order?
Values in table_types are taken directly from res, so why are they in different order?

Regards
Pawel

Comment: To ensure the values returned from the Oracle database are always in the same order, add an `ORDER BY` clause to your code e.g.: `ORDER BY column_name`

Comment: Ah yes, it wasn't displaying on my screen unless i highlighted it. I'll stay out of it as I know very little about Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

table_types is dictionary and dictionary doesn't store or display in the same order you have inserted.

The order of dictionary has to do with how they work internally and what order they end up in in the hash table. That in turn depends on the keys hash-value, the order they were inserted, and which Python implementation you are using.

The order is arbitrary (but not random) and it will never be useful to know which order it will be.

Comment: If you want in same order use OrderedDict [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)